# Regex pattern to find the longest vowel sequence

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

My below code works for locating the first match of vowel(s), in this case `'ua'` but how do I configure the regex to 1) search the entire string before ending at the first find and 2) once step 1 is fulfilled, determine which of all patterns shows the longest concurrency of vowels?

```
import re
s = "quality"
matches = re.search(r"[aeiou]+", s)
matchlist = matches.group().split(', ')
print(len(matchlist))
```

Comment: Grab all matches, then find the longest one, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/yiw5LZ).

Comment: Why you hating on `y`? It's a vowel sometimes too!!! `((?:[aeiou]|y(?![aeiou]))+)`

Comment: Mr Jibz, any feedback?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution was spot on

Comment: @Mr.Jibz Great, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Grab all matches, then find the longest one:

```
import re
s = "quality"
matches = re.findall(r"[aeiou]+", s) # Finds all chunks of vowel letters
print(max(matches, key=len))         # Gets the longest item in the list
# => ua
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yiw5LZ).